# jquery show specific div section when a button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have the following html and jQuery script and what I want to do is when a user clicks on a button to show the specific details of a .more_details class.
The thing is that now this is working but not the way I want.
When you click at the html button all of the html elements that are included in the .more_details are showing but I just want to show only the relevant one.
Any help would be appreciated.

The Html is as follows:

```
<div class="column effect">
 <button class="btn">Show More</button>

  <div class="more_details">
     this is shown on click of the button   
  </div><!-- more_details -->

</div><!-- column effect-->

<div class="column effect">
 <button class="btn">Show More</button>

  <div class="more_details">
     this is shown on click of the button
  </div><!-- more_details -->

</div><!-- column effect-->
```

Th jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.effect').on('click', 'button', showMoreLess);

});

function showMoreLess () {

  var buttonText = $(this).text();

  if (buttonText=="Show More"){

    $(this).text("Show Less");
    $('.more_details').show();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
  else {

    $(this).text("Show More");
    $('.more_details').hide();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('.more_details').show();
```

to this:

```
$(this).next('.more_details').show();
```

Why?

`$('.more_details')` selects all elements with the class `more_details`, where `$(this).next('.more_details')` selects only the element with the class `more_details` *relative* to the element that was clicked on. Do the same for your .hide() as well.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Las19qyj/)**